# Обновление элемента в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

При обновлении элемента

```
UPDATE `events` SET action='2011-11-01' and ...

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `prevev` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `nextev` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `action` date NOT NULL,
```

action получается 0000-00-00, не подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что у Вас сам запрос на UPDATE некорректный. Смущает AND в Вашем примере. Если Вы обновляете несколько полей, то попробуйте так:

```
UPDATE `events` SET `action`='2011-11-01', `nextev`='value' WHERE `id`=<YOUR_DESIRED_ID>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Подозрительный and у вас. Правильно так:

```
update events set
action='2011-11-01',
prevev=10
```

Если там будет `and`, то будет осуществлена попытка привести

```
'2011-11-01' and `field`=100
```

булевому типу, в итоге будет 0, что видимо равно нулевой ('0000-00-00') дате.